# Send/Receive Email with Google OAuth 2 and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth

I have used the following in a class:

```
public class AppFlowMetaData : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "nnnnnnnnnnnnn.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "nnnnnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"
        },
        Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        DataStore = new FileDataStore("Calendar.Api.Auth.Store")
    });

    public override string GetUserId(System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller)
    {
        var user = controller.Session["user"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Guid.NewGuid();
            controller.Session["user"] = user;
        }
        return user.ToString();
    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
}
```

And the following on a controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetaData()).AuthorizeAsync(token);   
        if(result.Credential != null)
        {
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "Calendar Test"
            });
            IList<CalendarListEntry> results = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
            List<Event> model = new List<Event>();
            foreach (var calendar in results)
            {
                Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(calendar.Id);
                var events = request.Execute().Items;

                foreach (var e in events)
                {
                    model.Add(e);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
```

This works well and I wanted to be able to send mails using gmail using the same process but I cannot find a scope or any details in the Google Api Documentation (which quite frankly is awful) to do this based on the same process.  I have seen 3rd party libraries using Imap elsewhere but this relies on passing the username/password which I don't want to do.

Can anyone help me to alter the above to be used for Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is a year old now, but it's one of the few I've found asking the question. I've managed to send email with the Gmail API using the following code. I'm saving the AccessToken and RefreshToken when the user logs into my site, and then plugging them into the method below. Thanks to Jason Pettys for pointing me in the right direction (http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/).

```
public string SendMail(string fromAddress, string toEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        //Construct the message
        var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toEmail, subject, body);
        mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(fromAddress));

        //Specify whether the body is HTML
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Convert to MimeMessage
        MimeMessage message = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);
        var rawMessage = message.ToString();

        var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "GoogleClientId",
                ClientSecret = "GoogleClientSecret"
            },
            Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose }
        });

        var token = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse()
            {
                AccessToken = MethodToRetrieveSavedAccessToken(),
                RefreshToken = MethodToRetrieveSavedRefreshToken()
            };

        //In my case the username is the same as the fromAddress
        var gmail = new GmailService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApplicationName = "App Name",
                HttpClientInitializer = new UserCredential(flow, fromAddress, token)
            });

        var result = gmail.Users.Messages.Send(new Message
            {
                Raw = Base64UrlEncode(rawMessage)
            }, "me").Execute();
        return result.Id;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts input string into a URL safe Base64 encoded string. Method thanks to Jason Pettys.
    /// http://jason.pettys.name/2014/10/27/sending-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-net-c/
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
          .Replace('+', '-')
          .Replace('/', '_')
          .Replace("=", "");
    }
```

Comment: What is MethodToRetrieveSavedAccessToken() and MethodToRetrieveSavedRefreshToken() ?

Comment: Sahil, those are just placeholders to read from the datastore where you have previously saved a user's Access and Refresh tokens. That code will vary based on your environment. I have mine in a SQL database.